# How to stop a while loop after looping x times

Tags: javascript

```
while(vowels != "NO" && vowels != "no" && vowels != "stop")
{
    vowels = prompt("Enter any vowel.");

    if (vowels != "a" && vowels != "A" && vowels != "e" && vowels != "E"
        && vowels != "i" && vowels != "I" && vowels != "o" && vowels != "O"
        && vowels != "u" && vowels != "U")
    {
        score+=-1;
    }
    else
    {
        score+=+1;
    }
}
```

How do I make it stop after 5 times?

Comment: In addition to stopping the loop with the conditions below, you can simplify your code greatly using [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). For instance your large if condition can be rewritten `['a','e','i','o','u'].indexOf(vowels.toLowerCase()) != -1`

Comment: `/^[aeiou]$/i.test(vowels)` :-P

Comment: @HunterMcMillen
Actually `String` also has `indexOf` method and it is supported in IE6 contrary to `Array.prototype.indexOf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `while` conditional statement add:

```
var i = 0;
while(vowels != "NO" && vowels != "no" && vowels != "stop" && i < 5)
{
   ...
   i++;
}
```

This will add a tick counter to your loop. You could also use a [`for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).

`for` loop example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    if (vowels != "NO" && vowels != "no" && vowels != "stop")
       break;
    vowels = prompt("Enter any vowel.");

    if (vowels != "a" && vowels != "A" && vowels != "e" && vowels != "E"
        && vowels != "i" && vowels != "I" && vowels != "o" && vowels != "O"
        && vowels != "u" && vowels != "U")
    {
        score+=-1;
    }
    else
    {
        score+=+1;
    }
}
```

Also, [a classic example of a tick counter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k0xgjUhEG3U). :)

**EDIT**

As @DRAX pointed out, you could write the `for` as:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5 && vowels != "NO" && vowels != "no" && vowels != "stop"; i++)
{
    vowels = prompt("Enter any vowel.");

    if (vowels != "a" && vowels != "A" && vowels != "e" && vowels != "E"
        && vowels != "i" && vowels != "I" && vowels != "o" && vowels != "O"
        && vowels != "u" && vowels != "U")
    {
        score+=-1;
    }
    else
    {
        score+=+1;
    }
}
```

This modifies the conditional of the `for`.

Comment: Because you are missing original condition: vowels != "NO" && vowels != "no" && vowels != "stop"

Comment: Actually I'd prefer for-loop with `break` on that additional condition.

Comment: I posted suggestion with `break`, however I got 2 downvotes in 20 sec, so I removed.

Comment: @kirilloid Thats what I was thinking haha

Comment: Yeah, now its better, now you got upvoted :)  I would suggest also this as second option: for (var i = 0; vowels != "NO" && vowels != "no" && vowels != "stop" && i < 5; i++)

Comment: @DRAX Hmmm... Yeah that would also work... I usually don't go for that approach although, habits:/

Answer (score 2):

```
    var cnt = 0;
    while(vowels != "NO" && vowels != "no" && vowels != "stop" && cnt <5)
    {
        cnt++;
        vowels = prompt("Enter any vowel.");

        if (vowels != "a" && vowels != "A" && vowels != "e" && vowels != "E" && vowels != "i"
        && vowels != "I" && vowels != "o" && vowels != "O" && vowels != "u" && vowels != "U")
        {
            score+=-1;
        }

        else
        {
            score+=+1;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Do you need score to be 5, or 5 loops?

Comment: otherwise, remove the cnt, and replace the cnt<5 with score < 5

Comment: `int cnt` in javascipt, really? =)

Comment: Yeah I don't use it often :) Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Feel the power of REGULAR EXPRESSIONS, TYPE COERCION and other 1337 $7UFF!

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if(/^(no|NO|stop)$/.test(vowels)) break;
    score -= 1 - (/^[aeiou]$/i.test(vowels=prompt("Enter any vowel.")) << 1);
}
```

PS: do not try to repeat that at home.

Comment: This isn't [tag:POPULARITY-CONTEST]?;)

Comment: Erm... didn't know about that. Just added my answer for the lulz.

Answer (score -1):

One way to loop a specific number of times is to use a `for` loop. You could, for instance, wrap your `while` loop within a `for` loop that has 5 iterations.